# Venue Search API Inaccurate Using "Near" Instead of "LL"

Tags: api, search, foursquare

When I search venues via API I get different results than the foursquare website. For example I'm looking for a venue named "Nopalito" near "San Francisco, CA". I'm under the impression this should return relevant matches:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?query=Nopalito&intent=match&near=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA

I only receive one result for a venue named "Invocation". However, when I run a similar query via foursquare.com website I get what I'd expect:

https://foursquare.com/search?tab=venueResults&q=Nopalito&lat=&lng=&near=San+Francisco%2Cca&source=q

The website search yields two venues named Nopalito in San Francisco, CA.

Seems like a very basic query with a limited number of potential results. What's up? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Okay, so as usual I answer my own question shortly beyond spending days beating my head against the wall. Check this out... remove &intent=match from my URL and bada-bing. Two matches for Nopalito. I'm leaving this as an open question however, since from the documentation I believe my original query was still correct. I challenge you to prove me wrong foursquare. CHALLENGE.

Comment: seems like the challenge was met? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance I'd suggest dropping intent=match, intent=match makes a very restrictive query. The purpose of intent=match (from https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search ) is to

> "Finds venues that are are nearly-exact matches for the given query and ll. This is helpful when trying to correlate an existing place database with foursquare's. It is highly sensitive to the provided location. The results will be sorted best match first, taking distance and spelling mistakes/variations into account."

I'd recommend intent=browse for this type of query.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think your response really answers the underlying issue. Although removing intent=match helps, it isn't really explainable. I also get back way more results than necessary. The name of the venue I'm providing is an exact match to what they have in their db. I'd like to see foursquare correct this, or at least provide better documentation on why it doesn't work intuitively. Thanks though.

Comment: So the purpose of intent=match is to match a specific venue, so trying to do a city search with it isn't a great idea. If you had a specific lat/long that the venue was close to then it would make more sense. As the api documents say "It is highly sensitive to the provided location".

Comment: I agree that lat/lon is probably ideal, but unfortunately I don't have it in my use case. I have other examples where name/city is 1:1 with a result, but I can see your point. Must be a design decision. Match just requires very narrow criteria. Still wish this were a little clearer in documentation, but I'll make this an answer after the clarification.